# regex to extract longest substring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expressions that extracts a string with the following properties:

1. The first letter of each word is a capital letter
2. & signs are allowed as standalone words
3. periods are allowed in words
4. longest substring in the string with these properties

I tried the following regex but it was not working for me

```
r'[A-Z](\w|\.)*(\s(([A-Z](\w|\.)*)|&))*
```

Comment: `not working` means matching things it shouldn't, not matching things it should, or other technical difficulties?

Comment: Do you have some current vs desired input/output pairs?

Comment: not matching things it should

Comment: Regular expressions can match only patterns. Longest string is NOT a way to express a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is to match patterns. You can use dynamic programming to solve this longest substring problem.

```
string = raw_input()
longest_substring = [0]

for i in range(len(string)):
    pre_longest = longest_substring[-1]
    if pre_longest == 0:
       if string[i].isupper() or string[i] == '&':
            cur_longest = 1
        else:
            cur_longest = 0
    else:
        if i > 0 and string[i-1] == '&':
            cur_longest = 0
        elif string[i].isalpha() or string[i] == '.':
            cur_longest = pre_longest + 1
        else:
            cur_longest = 0
    longest_substring.append(cur_longest)

print longest_substring
```